# Why am I receiving a PDO Exception when Uploaing to the Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to upload some data to a MySQl DB using a PDO object. However, whenever I attempt to submit the query it throws a PDOException. I have followed multiple tutorials by the book and this should be a simple task. I have no idea why it throws an exception.

Here is my code:

```
    // Add a new image data to db and return ID (ID column of pelagicsschema.images)
    public  function addImage(string $name, string $species, string $rarity, string $description){
    //Global PDO Object
    global $pdo;
    //trim strings to remove extra spaces
    $name = trim($name);
    $species = trim($species);
    $rarity = trim($rarity);
    $description = trim($description);



   // Add the new Image

   /* Insert query template */
   $query = 'INSERT INTO pelagicsSchema.images (Name,Species,Rarity,Description) VALUES    (:name,:species,:rarity,:description)';
   /* Values array for PDO */
   $values = array(':name'=>$name, ':species'=>$species, ':rarity'=>$rarity, ':description'=>$description);
   /* Execute the query */
   try
   {
       $res = $pdo->prepare($query);
       $res->execute($values);
   }
   catch (PDOException $e)
   {
      /* If there is a PDO exception, throw a standard exception */
      throw new Exception('Database query error');
   }

       /* Return the new ID */
        return $pdo->lastInsertId();
    }
```

To Note:
The query executes perfectly if I use exec() instead of prepare/execute, but as this request will be made multiple times with different data, I believe prepare/execute is the way to go.

EDIT: The Exception that I am receiving is:

```
SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'Name' at row 1
```

Does this mean I need to change the datatype for that column in my DB?
Currently it is set to VARCHAR(30).

Comment: Instead of throwing a new exception with a custom message and discarding the PDOException, check what that exception actually says.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I would LOVE to. How do I do that?

Comment: While developing, in your `catch`-block, just add: `die($e->getMessage());` (before your `throw`) and it should show you the message. When you've debugged the issue, you should probably change `die()` to some function/method that logs the message instead.

Comment: You can also pass the message to the new exception: `throw new Exception($e->getMessage());`, but honestly, I don't really see the point of catching the first exception and throwing a new, more generic one in the first place. You could simply remove your `try/catch` since it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: The type of you database table column should be chosen on that you expect to save in this column. If you know that the length of the value of `name` can be longer than 30 chars you should change it to VARCHAR(255) (or the maximum expected length for name)! Alternatively set a length restriction on the input field for `name`.

Comment: Please remove try/ catch. You don't need it.

Comment: Please also check the charset. If it is not utf8mb4 then you need to change it.

Comment: @Dharman - I will do this, but how will I catch any errors that this might throw?

Comment: Changing the datatype for all columns to VARCHAR(300) and the charset to utf8mb4 has solved the problem! Did not post as answer because I cannot explain the problem and solution in detailed terms.

Comment: Why do you want to catch the exceptions? Leave them alone.

Comment: @Dharman - Surely catching exceptions is good practice so that I can better determine where and what is going wrong when something does?

Comment: No, you should only ever catch exceptions if you need to recover from it.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to insert data that is longer that the column definition's maximum size.

If you wanna store strings bigger than 255 characters, you should use another type for the `name` column definition, `text` for example.

http://www.sqlerror.de/db2_sql_error_-404_sqlstate_22001.html